# Color of ants in A Bug's Life (1998)

Tags: a-bugs-life

[image]

Why were ants in the movie *A Bug's Life* (1998) shown in a color which is anything but the true color of any ant species?

Comment: Probably because the _actual_ color of most ant species are dull and boring and don't appeal to children like bright and exciting colors do.  If you're curious about staying true to ant species, I would be more concerned with the activities of the ants throughout the film rather than their color :P

Comment: I didn't know that gray or bluish-gray or pinkish blue are resplendent and exciting colors ...

Comment: Sure...but, those colors are definitely more appealing than a brown/black color that most ants are.  It also looks like they have some sort of shine to their color.  It's just more appealing to the eye and more attractive to the target audience, imo.  After all, this is an animated film.  It's not too much of a stretch to exaggerate or completely change the look of _anything_ :)

Comment: You're worried about their colour but not at all by the fact they can speak, or have mammalian eyes?

Comment: @Tetsujin, no I am not worried, given that all other bugs portrayed in the film retained their real colors, and hence the question.

Comment: Yeah...because I always see blue caterpillars with pink hands like Absolem the Caterpillar from _Alice in Wonderland_ ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely because realistic ants didn't look kid-friendly. [This tor.com article discusses this somewhat](https://www.tor.com/2017/02/23/insects-and-corporate-infighting-a-bugs-life/):

> Cute and friendly bugs proved difficult for two different reasons. For
>   one, these were, after all, bugs, and for two, the Pixar rendering
>   systems were still not capable of creating “soft” looking, variant
>   textures, but only hard, shiny, plastic like surfaces. In many ways,
>   that plasticity was ideal for portraying the often smooth exoskeleton
>   of ants — but **unfortunately, the more the ants looked like ants, the
>   less friendly (to humans and small children) they seemed.** The usual
>   cartoon touch of just creating bigger eyes, often associated with
>   “cuteness” (what Disney had done, well back in the day, to make Mickey
>   Mouse look “cuter” and more approachable) also tended to backfire,
>   since large eyed ants on a huge movie screen looked, well, like rather
>   terrifying giant ants with unusually large and scary eyes.
>
> Stuck on both the eye and surface rendering problem, the animators
>   tried a different approach: making the ants more human looking.
>   Instead of the standard six ant legs, for instance, the ants in A
>   Bug’s Life have two legs and two arms—and fingers and toes. Even more
>   importantly, they walk—or scurry—upright—making them look a little
>   more like humans dressed in bug costumes than actual bugs.

Comment: The people who made and anybody who saw Antz could probably attest to this.